# How can I integrate Highcharts with TinyMCE in React

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, tinymce, react-highcharts, tinymce-plugins

I have data for Rich Text Box coming from backend, I populate timyMCE with that data. I can see everything except the Charts which are integrated using Highcharts. How can I show these charts in TinyMCE Rich Text Box in react.

Comment: Have you already seen this article? https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/charting-with-tinymce-and-highcharts/

Comment: I've tried it, nothing happens. I am importing those 4 files after downloading them to my index.html